# Why does Rust std::io:::write_all() takes so much time on "libsystem_kernel.dylib`close"?

Tags: rust

I am writing an application in Rust where I implemented this method to append data to a file:

```rust
    fn write_append(&self, path: PathBuf, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), ShError> {
        let file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).append(true).create(true).open(path)?;

        let mut new_line = data.to_vec();
        new_line.push(10);// \n character

        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);

        match writer.write_all(&new_line) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(_) => Err(ShError::new(ShErrorKind::Internal, "Error writing entity file")),
        }
    }
```

I am profiling the application with `cargo flamegraph` and in some place the bottom of stack looks like this:

[image: Flamegraph]

Now I wonder why does the CPU **spend more time on closing the file** (the `libsystem_kernel.dylib close` block) than actually opening the file and writing the data?

Am I reading this wrong?

PS: I am on a MacBookPro M1

Comment: I could be wrong but it could be that closing the file forces delayed writes to actually take place.

Comment: Likely because closing the file includes flushing it. You don't provide any information but I'd assume your input `data` is under the 8k default capacity of the `BufWriter` so pretty much nothing happens until the `BufWriter` gets closed, and then data going through the BufWriter would still be going through the OS and then disk caches. Closing the file thus means flushing the BufWriter to the file, then flushing the file to disk, and flushing the disk to ensure the file is durably persisted.

Comment: You should try flushing the file explicitely, it ought create a large new cost, and significantly reduce the cost of closing the file.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I tried flushing explicitly, but the flamegraph looks the same. You are right I am writing less than 4k bytes, but I don't think that's the reason because the `libsystem_kernel.dylib`write ` block is smaller than the "close" block...